# Global variable in controller cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

What's the way to have a global variable inside a controller?

I have tried to do it using beforeFilter but it is not accessible from the others functions.

Can it only be done using `Configure::read` and `Configure::write`

Comment: you need to explain more what it is used for. otherwise one can only guess. and in general Configure is a very easy and clean way to do that, yes.

Comment: Just want to share some variables with more than one function. Something like $isOwner, or $isAdmin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can set variable accessible in any controller in your AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $myGlobalVar;  

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
         //this can be anything array, object, string, etc .....
         $this->myGlobalVar = "test2";
    }
 }
```

then in your other controller you can access variable anywhere like this

```
class TestController extends AppController {

    public function index() {

        debug($this->myGlobalVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it in the index function? Wouldn't it be in the beforeFilter one?

Comment: its just an example, should be accesible anywhere in any controller.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but i not use it as the variables read info from models and cake doesn't allow many calls on there.