# global controller variable not working

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables

I'm running CakePHP 2.4.1 and PHP 5.5.3.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638962/global-variable-in-controller-cakephp-2) about how to create/write to/access a global variable, but it's not working for me. I'm doing something like this:

```
class SploopsController extends AppController {
    public $crung;

    public function process() {
        $this->crung = 'zax';
    }

    public function download() {
        $this->response->body($this->crung);
        $this->response->type('text/plain');
        $this->response->download('results.txt');
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

But the downloaded file `results.txt` is blank, i.e. `$this->crung` is empty. (If I replace `$this->crung` with a simple string like `'Granjo'` it works as intended.) Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?

Additionally, Configure::write and Configure::read aren't working for me either (if I call each within a function of the Controller).

Here's the context: I create an array with results to a query in process(), and display them in process.ctp, and I want to have a button that can download these results to a text file in a more text friendly format. So I want to make a global array, that I can modify in process() and then access in download().

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `procees` before setting

```
public function download() {
    $this->process();
    $this->response->body($this->crung);
    $this->response->type('text/plain');
    $this->response->download('results.txt');
    return $this->response;
}
```

**Edit**

```
public function process() {
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) { // assuming you're processing the user entered data by means of post
        $this->Session->write('crung', 'zax');
        $this->Session->write('data', $this->request->data);
    }
}

public function download() {
    $this->crung = $this->Session->read('crung');
    $data = $this->Session->read('data'); // you can process the data in the way you want.

    $this->response->body($this->crung);
    $this->response->type('text/plain');
    $this->response->download('results.txt');
    return $this->response;
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but process() uses user-entered data, which no longer exists when I'm calling it from download().

Comment: Why don't you post the user-entered data to to the `download` action ?

Comment: I looked into this, it's tricky to pass an array (especially a potentially large array) from the view back to the controller.

Comment: you can serialize the array before saving to the session and get the value by unserializing it.

Comment: Okay, I think I'll try this. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier alternative. Thanks!

Comment: This worked. Accepting your answer for the comment on serializing the session variable.

Comment: um, yeah now i edited my answer, thanks for the info :) @AD7six

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `process()` function before use `$this->crung` like as below

```
public function process() {
    $this->crung = 'zax';
}

public function download() {
    $this->process();
    $this->response->body($this->crung);
    $this->response->type('text/plain');
    $this->response->download('results.txt');
    return $this->response;
}
```

else you can use `beforeFilter()` function that will be called before your `download()` function. This is useful when you need to assign values

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
     $this->crung = 'zax';
}
```

Comment: nice idea, but process() uses user-entered data, which no longer exists when I'm calling it from download().

Comment: so download() is just after the process() method?

Comment: Use download method direct for handle use-entered data.

Comment: then call download() function inside process() method.

Comment: process() takes them to a screen where they see their data in a nice-looking table. Then if they want the raw text data, from there, they can press the download link.

Comment: session doesn't let me store arrays, only single variables.