# Configure::read and controller global variabel not working in cakephp 2.10.12

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.10.12 and I'm creating a global in variabel in my controller as shown below :

```
class TestsController extends AppController {

    ....
    public $myConverter;    
    public $myLocale = '';
    public $myTimezone =  '';
    public $myCurr = '';
    ...
 }
```

Then I initialized those variabels in a function of controller :

```
public function converterUtil() {
        $this->myConverter = new ConverterUtil();
        if (!empty($this->params['pass'][0])) {
            switch ($this->params['pass'][0]) {
                case 'jpn':
                    Configure::write('Config.language','jpn');
                    $this->myLocale = 'ja_jp';
                    $this->myTimezone =  'Asia/Tokyo';
                    $this->myCurr = 'JPY';
                    break;
                case 'idn':
                    Configure::write('Config.language','idn');
                    $this->myLocale = 'id_ID';
                    $this->myTimezone =  'Asia/Jakarta';
                    $this->myCurr = 'IDR';
                    break;
                case 'eng':
                    Configure::write('Config.language','eng');
                    $this->myLocale = 'en_US';
                    $this->myTimezone =  'America/New_York';
                    $this->myCurr = 'USD';
                    break;  
                default:
                    Configure::write('Config.language','eng');
                    $this->myLocale = 'en_US';
                    $this->myTimezone =  'America/New_York';
                    $this->myCurr = 'USD';
                    break;
            }
            $this->myConverter->init($this->myLocale, $this->myTimezone, $this->myCurr);

        }else {
            // debug('empty');
        }
        $testData = $this->Test->find('all');
        // debug($this->myLocale);

        $this->set('test_data', $testData);
        $this->set('locale', $this->myLocale);
        $this->set('timezone', $this->myTimezone);
        $this->set('curr', $this->myCurr);
}
```

Then I access those variabel in other function in the same controller :

```
    public function saveTests() {
        $msg = [];
        $this->Test->set($this->request->data('content'));
        $this->log('isi data content');
        $this->log($this->myLocale);
        $this->log($this->myTimezone);
        $this->log($this->myCurr);
        ....
}
```

The problem is `$this->myLocale, $this->myTimezone` and `$this->myCurr` are empty when I called in saveTest function. And saveTest function is called when I do a postRequest from frontend. So what's the problem here ?
I have tried to use `Configure::write` and `Configure::read`. but `Configure::read` also empty when it's used in `saveTest()`.
Thank you

Note:
example from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638962/global-variable-in-controller-cakephp-2) is not working for me

Comment: Is `converterUtil` being called by one page load, and then `saveTest` by a later page load?

Comment: ConverterUtil is called the first time page is loaded. And the savetest is called when button 'save' is clicked'

Comment: That was my suspicion. PHP is not a persistent process. When the first page is loaded, it will run your `converterUtil`. The output of that page is sent to your browser, and PHP ends and discards all information that it had. When you click "Save", an entirely new process is started up to handle that request. It has no memory whatsoever of what has ever gone before. Any time that you need the results of `converterUtil` to be available, you need to make sure that it has been called during the *current* process.

Comment: I thought that Configure::write will gonna save any variabel in a global way so no matter what happen. It will be always available in whole controller unless we delete it using Configure::delete or configure::consume...
but, I'm not so sure.

Comment: But, thanks for your info Greg Shcmidt

Comment: It will be available in a global way *for the duration of the process*, which is a single page load. If you want data to last from one page to the next, you need to use sessions instead.